# Python. Replacing reg.ex string in multiple files and save it

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a problem with my script. I need to replace(or delete) a string defined in simple reg.ex in multiple files in structure and save it.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. So far it adds what it finds and adds replaced string at the end.

```
import os
import re
path = input()
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
    for eachXLF in files:
        os.chdir(root)
        openXLF = open(eachXLF, 'r+')
        XLF = openXLF.read()
        repl = re.sub(r'<seg-source>(.*?)</seg-source>', 'xxx', XLF)
        openXLF.write(repl)
        openXLF.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek) to the 0th position in the file and then [`truncate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate) it:

```
openXLF = open(eachXLF, 'r+')
XLF = openXLF.read()
repl = re.sub(r'<seg-source>(.*?)</seg-source>', 'xxx', XLF)
openXLF.seek(0)
openXLF.write(repl)
openXLF.truncate()
openXLF.close()
```